# Implementing the RETR FTP command Java

Tags: java, ftp

Hello I am trying to implement the RETR FTP command in order to download a file from a remote server. I am doing this while being in FTP passive mode. The problem I am facing is that after issuing the RETR command I get a response from the server which looks like this:

```
2015/11/11 23:08:11: >RETR /pub/site/README
2015/11/11 23:08:13: <150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /pub/site/README (175 bytes).
```

Which is normal and is exactly what I expect to get. After this though instead of the file being download I get nothing other than an IOException. I have no clue as to what the problem is. Can anyone help? Here is the method that implements the RETR command:

```
public synchronized boolean retr(String fileName) throws IOException {

        Trace.connection = true;
        String response = null;

        if(!isBinary && !isPassive){
            passv();
        }

        String fullPath = pwd() + "/" + fileName;
        Trace.trc("Will retrieve the following file: " + fullPath);

        sendLine("RETR " + fullPath);
        response = readLine();
        if(!response.startsWith("150")){
            throw new IOException("Unable to download file from the remote server");
        }   

        BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(dataSocket.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName)));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(bytesRead);
        }
        output.close();
        input.close();

        if(response.startsWith("226")){
            isPassive = false;
            return true;
        }else{
            throw new IOException("Error");
        }
    }
```

And here is the exception I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Error
    at connectors.FtpConnection.retr(FtpConnection.java:275)
    at ui.FtpDialog.fileDlBtActionPerformed(FtpDialog.java:339)
    at ui.FtpDialog.access$300(FtpDialog.java:23)
    at ui.FtpDialog$4.actionPerformed(FtpDialog.java:178)
```

Comment: I guess, you need to check, what you have in FtpConnection.java at line 275, FtpDialog.java line 339, FtpDialog.java line 23 and FtpDialog.java line 178.

Comment: Line 275 is the end of the method. Line 339 is where the method is called. So no problems there. The problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your code:

```
    if(response.startsWith("226")){
        isPassive = false;
        return true;
    }else{
        throw new IOException("Error");
    }
```

Obviously, you throw an IOException because your responce starts with "150", not "226"

```
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /pub/site/README (175 bytes).
```

Answer (score 0):

What you mention is checked here:

```
sendLine("RETR " + fullPath);
response = readLine();
if(!response.startsWith("150")){
throw new IOException("Unable to download file from the remote server");
}
```

As you can see if the response for issuing the RETR command is indeed "150" then the code proceeds to do it's job which is to download the file from the server. What the code does in the part you mention is to check for the "226" reply which signifies that everything has completed corretly. The problem as far as I can tell is the fact that the file is never being actually downloaded.